# Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' Can't configure antMatchers after anyRequest

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I get this error after upgrading spring boot version to 2.6.2 :

`Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't configure antMatchers after anyRequest`

This is my securityConfig class extends fromn WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    super.configure(http);
    http.csrf().disable().headers().frameOptions().disable().and().sessionManagement()
        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/**")
        .authenticated().and()
        .addFilterAfter(new TokenAuthenticationProcessingFilter(
            new PiAuthenticationProvider(
                new ApplicationPropertiesDataAdapterPi(this.applicationProperties)),
            "/api/**", null, new CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler(),
            AuthTokenUtil::extractXAuthorizationToken), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call super.configure(http) it actually does the following:

```
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        this.logger.debug("Using default configure(HttpSecurity). "
                + "If subclassed this will potentially override subclass configure(HttpSecurity).");
        http.authorizeRequests((requests) -> requests.anyRequest().authenticated());
        http.formLogin();
        http.httpBasic();
    }
```

And after that you are trying to execute .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/**") once again which causes this error. So simply don't call super.configure(http) and implement all logic you need in your method

Comment: Thanks you so much @Andrey Grigoriev. It resolved the issue. But login UI - when call to this Localhost:8080 via browser) has vanished after removing the  super.configure(http). - Is there any solution for implement that again?

Comment: Need more details. From the code you posted I see that you have both SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS and formLogin(), which can cause problems

Comment: After removing the  super.configure(http);  deafult login form disappear and show the HATEOAS when call to localhost:8080 via browser. For that I excluded the RepositoryRestMvcAutoConfiguration.class like this.    
  @SpringBootApplication(exclude = RepositoryRestMvcAutoConfiguration.class). It resolved the problem. Thanks a lot @Andrey Grigoriev for the help. You saved my day

Answer (score 0):

there is one other case also when you can get this error
**Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception**

code which throws this exception

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/authenticate").permitAll()
            .anyRequest();
}
```

fix: append **.authenticated()** method

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/authenticate").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated();
}
```